# incorrect syntax near 'A'

Tags: mysql, .net

What could be wrong with this *select* statement? I get an error called ***incorrect syntax near 'A'***.

Since I am more used to write queries in postgreSQL, my guess is that MySQL has a bit different syntax.

```
cmd.CommandText = "WITH CurrentStop AS (SELECT[Stop Id] FROM Stops WHERE[Route Id] = " + 
                  routeId + "AND Serial = " + stopsDriven + ")" +
                  "SELECT A.Firstname, A.Lastname, B.Make, B.Capacity, B.Route, D.Name" +
                  "FROM Driver A, Bus B, CurrentStop C, Stop D" +
                  "WHERE A.Id = " + row[0] + "AND B.[Bus Id] = " + row[1] + "AND C.[Stop Id] = D.[Stop Id]";
```

By the way, all inputs are in system only so no SQL injection could possibly happen.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support common table expressions.

Comment: I was going to give you a working query where the CTE has been embedded in your main query, but your join conditions don't make sense, and mostly you seem to be cross joining the tables together - probably not what you want, or what the problem requires.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need to select only one row, so for each table I am giving primary key in WHERE clause. However, it might be wrong somewhere. Need to double check that

Comment: Clean up the joins in your query, and then just embed the CTE in the query itself.  This should always work, in SQL Server, MySQL, or any database.

Comment: Dai, apologies for reverting your edit but it didn't actually *add* anything to the question and, in fact, it *hid* information that was rather central to the problem (or at least *one* problem).

Answer (score 0):

Print out the query before trying to execute it and examine it closely. This solves a large chunk of the "what's wrong with my dynamically generated query?" style questions we see here.

For example, I'd be wary of the lack of space between (not necessarily an exhaustive list, these are just the ones I noticed):

- `routeId` and the following `AND`;
- `row[0]` and the following `AND`;
- `row[1]` and the following `AND`;
- `D.Name` and the following `FROM`; and
- `Stop D` and the following `WHERE`.

Those last two are definitely problematic since, while it is *possible* the variables may end in a space (though unusual), the fixed strings *certainly* don't. And both may be causing the specific error you see since they would come out as:

```
D.NameFROM Driver A
Stop DWHERE A.
```